# SQL - Check which years contain data

Tags: sql, mysql

How to select only years from mysql database (but only those years which contain data)?

The [PHP time() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) is used to populate the date in the database. There are more then 10,000 records stored since 2006...

I would like to categorize data by date (firstly, user selects year, then month, than day...). I'd also like to be able to use a similar approach for selection by months and/or days.

Comment: I edited post... in database is stored value of php time() function, not mysql time() (I didn't know that it exists :))

Comment: This alternative solution of mine is not perfect because you have to take care of leap year which complicates situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are MySQL functions that make it possible to extract year/month/date information from a date, but they work on the MySQL's date type. So first you need to convert your UNIX timestamp to date, using `FROM_UNIXTIME(date)` and then extract the part of the information you want. See the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for a list of available date functions. So, for example to get all years you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) FORM table;
```

If you want to later filter the actual results, you can use this to get all rows from year 2009:

```
SELECT ... WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 2009
```

Unless you have a good reason for storing the timestamp in the database, I'd suggest to convert the column to the MySQL's `datetime` type. That will allow you to use an index to speed up the query. MySQL can't create indexes using specific functions, so you can't use `YEAR()` in the query, but you can do for example:

```
SELECT ... WHERE date >= 2009 AND date <= 2009;
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't convert current datetype because it's very complex portal and changing this would be hard job. I'll figure out some other solution but in future I'll have this solution on mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just edited my post, I think that this is best solution if we take into consideration that I'm using UNIX timestamp in mysql as date format

Comment: I don't really understand how is that better than `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) FORM table`.

Comment: I can't use this solution you're suggesting because time format that is stored in my database is NOT mysql date format, it's UNIX timestamp. Or I can use it even with unix timestamp?

Comment: The whole point of `FROM_UNIXTIME(date)` is to convert the date from UNIX timestamp to a regular datetime.

Comment: Ooooh, I'm sorry, I thought you were suggesting me to convert datetype and store it as such. Well, now the life is much more beautiful :)
Thank you Lukáš

Answer (score 2):

> How to select only years from mysql database (but only those years which contain data)?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(YEAR(datecolumn))
FROM    mytable
```

> I would like to categorize data by date (firstly, user selects year, then month, than day...). I'd also like to be able to use a similar approach for selection by months and/or days.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(MONTH(datecolumn))
FROM    mytable
WHERE   datecolumn >= CAST(CONCAT($year, '-01-01') AS DATETIME)
        AND datecolumn < CAST(CONCAT($year + 1, '-01-01') AS DATETIME)


SELECT  DISTINCT(DAY(datecolumn))
FROM    mytable
WHERE   datecolumn >= CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', $year, $month, '01') AS DATETIME)
        AND datecolumn < CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', $year, $month, '01') AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If you store what `PHP` `time()` returns in your columns, use this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(datecolumn)))
FROM    mytable

SELECT  DISTINCT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datecolumn)))
FROM    mytable
WHERE   datecolumn >= CAST(CONCAT($year, '-01-01') AS DATETIME)
        AND datecolumn < CAST(CONCAT($year + 1, '-01-01') AS DATETIME)

SELECT  DISTINCT(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(datecolumn)))
FROM    mytable
WHERE   datecolumn >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', $year, $month, '01') AS DATETIME))
        AND datecolumn < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', $year, $month, '01') AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Note that the conditions we use here are *sargable*: `datecolumn` is the only thing on one side of the expression, and an index can be used to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sql you want is below. I tested these statements on my data which is stores as a mysql date, but the from_unixtime should do the conversion so that the rest works as you want.

```
-- Get year and counts
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y') AS raw_date,
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y') AS format_date,
       COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date)) AS num_activities
  FROM date_table
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y'),
          DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y');

-- Get month/year and counts     
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y%m') AS raw_date,
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%M %Y') AS format_date,
       COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date)) AS num_activities
  FROM date_table
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y%m'),
          DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%M %Y');

-- Get date and counts
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y%m%d') AS raw_date,
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%M %d, %Y') AS format_date,
       COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date)) AS num_activities
  FROM date_table
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%Y%m%d'),
          DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date), '%M %d, %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MySQL Extract Function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Comment: I edited my answer... I don't know if this extract function can handle format of php time() (11-digits number)