# Most efficient way to get month and year coverage data from a Postgres dataset

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

What is the most efficient / common pattern from model/table and Postgres query perspective, for getting a list of available months (and years) from a given dataset?

e.g, 10,000+ rows of data with a date column. The data covers some months in a given year but not others. I want to be able to query to find out which months/years we have data for and output that result.

Although likely not that relevant, I am using Sequelize as the ORM.

Comment: Sorry, Postgres - corrected question

Comment: In SQL you could do `select distinct date_trunc('month', the_date_column) from the_table`

Answer (score 0):

I got most of the way there from [SQL - Check which years contain data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548110/sql-check-which-years-contain-data?rq=1)

and comment from @a_horse_with_no_name

And then using Postgres syntax so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_PART('year', CAST("orderDate" AS DATE)) FROM public."Orders"
```

(For distinct years)

Comment: The cast to a date is unnecessary as it won't change the year